# Variable from lookup in a foreach block in Azure datafactory

Tags: azure, variables, factory, names

I'm trying to set up a simple pipeline in ADF. First step is selecting access tokens and logfilenames from a table on an MSSQL server. This works ok, preview shows a table containing two columns; token and logfilename. After this lookup I have a foreach loop which needs to do http requests to a REST API using the values in the columns token and logfilename. As items, in the foreach block, I set @activity('nameoftheactivity').output. In the foreach loop is a copy block. Source of this copy block is a REST API with its base URL (https://api.domain.com/v2/), relative URL is set as

`@concat('logfile/',dataset().ForEachLogfilename,'.',formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.log/json?access_token=',dataset().ForEachToken)`

The ForEachLogfilename and the ForEachToken are set as Dataset properties with values as

`@{item().token} and @{item().logfilename}`

When I hit the preview button Azure suggest that I set values for @item().token and @item().logfilename which I do as suggested. A click on finish AND I HAVE DATA from the rest API. But only with the preview data... It just errors when I perform a "trigger now"... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!
instead of
`@concat('logfile/',dataset().ForEachLogfilename,'.',formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.log/json?access_token=',dataset().ForEachToken)`

I had to use

`@concat('logfile/',item().logfilename,'.',formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.log/json?access_token=',item().token)`

in the "Add dynamic content" field....